# How can I prevent SVG elements from resizing in the browser?

Tags: html, css, svg

Below is a screen capture of a problem I have encountered many times already, which I have ignored, but now it sorts of bothers me.

[image: SVG Resize]

The relevant code for this snippet is

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}
.labelContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 48px;
}
.label {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="labelContainer">
    <span class="label">Super Transporter Company 3000 Ltd.</span>
    <svg width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="width:24px !important;">
      <path d="M10,17L15,12L10,7V17Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="labelContainer">
    <span class="label">Super Transporter Company 3000 Ltd.</span>
    <svg width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="width:24px !important;">
      <path d="M10,17L15,12L10,7V17Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Why does this happen? How can I prevent the SVG element from resizing?

Comment: Add a unit to the inline width and height

Comment: @AlePlo you're on the right tack, but it's `viewBox` that needs to have units, `width` and `height` don't change anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Browser set `min-width` and `min-height` for `svg` elements to `"auto"` by default. So when it render your `svg` and see that you have not set the `min-width`, then it will shrink it as much as it can to fit more text.

So you have to set `min-width` attribute for `svg` element.

Comment: Don't forget to add `max-width: 24px;` as well to prevent it from turning over large

Comment: Ah! Nice catch!

Comment: But why doesn't `width` alone work?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa width alone, does not prevent browser from squeezing it when there is not enough space. so you should set min-width and width together, if you don't want it to be squashed.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that the parent element was applying a flex-shrink on the child elements even though they were not shown in the css. Just setting `flex-shrink: 0` on the target element fixed my issue.